# gapi is undefined in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-api-client

I run this code when the page loads as per the google documentation:

```
(function() {

    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);

})();
```

And this is my code:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    'client_id': 'my_client_id', 
    'immediate': 'false', 
    'response_type':'token', 
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
}, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

In the console if I access `gapi` I see the object. However, if I use a breakpoint at that code block, `gapi` is undefined. Now, the code I've pasted here is loaded via content script. How can I load the `gapi` library into the content script?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because of the [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). Content scripts cannot access code in the page context, and adding a script tag injects code in the page context.
When you execute code in the page's JavaScript console, you're executing it in the page's context.

You should probably use the [identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the Google JS client asynchronously.
You then try to use it immediately, before it finishes loading.  That won't work.

Instead, you can either load it synchronously (using a normal `<script src="">` tag), or only run your code after the async script loads (eg, using `jQuery.getScript()`).

Comment: Before i run the code that depends on `gapi`, the client object (`gapi`) exists. For some reason when it is accessed in the content script, the object does not exist. any ideas?